# SSIS Script Task Check if a folder is empty

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

Within a SSIS Script Task, I have the below code that checks if a folder is empty.  I then want to pass if it is or not into the variable 'Dim_File_Count' and use a Precedence constraint to move onto the next task if successful.  However my code keeps stating the folder is empty, even when it's not:

```
public void Main()
{
    //string FolderName = Dts.Variables["User::Tech_Dim"].Value.ToString();

    if (File.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::Tech_Dim"].Value.ToString())==false)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Dim_File_Count"].Value = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("folder empty");
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Dim_File_Count"].Value = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("folder is not empty");
    }



    Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Comment: Try removing "ToString()".  The value returned is already a string.

Comment: `File.Exists` checks if a specified file exists. Feeding it the name of a directory will always fail. Use `Directory.GetFiles(...).Any()` (or, less memory, `new DirectoryInfo(...).EnumerateFiles().Any()`).

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work: 
if Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables["User::Tech_Dim"].Value.ToString()).Any();

Comment: Also tried this and it doesn't work:
if new DirectoryInfo(Dts.Variables["User::Tech_Dim"].Value.ToString()).EnumerateFiles().Any()) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Length` property of the `GetFiles` method of the `Directory` class to check if there are any files in the specified folder.  The optional third `SearchOption` parameter of `GetFiles` can be used if searching sub-directories is necessary, i.e. `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, with the default checking only the parent folder.

```
    if (Directory.GetFiles(Dts.Variables["User::Tech_Dim"].Value.ToString(), "*").Length > 0)
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Dim_File_Count"].Value = 0;
        MessageBox.Show("folder empty");
    }
    else
    {
        Dts.Variables["User::Dim_File_Count"].Value = 1;
        MessageBox.Show("folder is not empty");
    }
```